# how solve this problem with import pysal in conda?

Tags: python, numba, pysal

I installed `pysal` in conda with pyton 3.7(`conda install -c conda-forge pysal`),but I try to import it and I get this error:

```
runfile('D:/2019-1/Cartografia Geotecnica/Talleres&cod/loco.py', wdir='D:/2019-1/Cartografia Geotecnica/Talleres&cod')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\2019-1\Cartografia Geotecnica\Talleres&cod\loco.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pysal

  File "C:\Users\Blad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pysal\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import explore

  File "C:\Users\Blad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pysal\explore\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    import giddy

  File "C:\Users\Blad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\giddy\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import ergodic

  File "C:\Users\Blad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\giddy\ergodic.py", line 10, in <module>
    import quantecon as qe

  File "C:\Users\Blad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\quantecon\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import game_theory

  File "C:\Users\Blad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\quantecon\game_theory\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .support_enumeration import support_enumeration, support_enumeration_gen

  File "C:\Users\Blad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\quantecon\game_theory\support_enumeration.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ..util.numba import _numba_linalg_solve

  File "C:\Users\Blad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\quantecon\util\numba.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numba.targets.linalg import _LAPACK

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numba.targets.linalg'
```

Help me ,please, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to update also package quantecon to version 0.4.7 by using:

```
conda update quantecon=0.4.7
```